# Receive a notification when I am at these coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I receive a notification when my position is equal to the position of a waypoint?

I use a Google Map Activity with some waypoints and I need to receive a notification when I am next to one of these also if the application is on background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LatLng latLngA = new LatLng(12.3456789,98.7654321); // Your Current Location
LatLng latLngB = new LatLng(98.7654321,12.3456789); // Notification coordinates
double distance = latLngA.distanceTo(latLngB);
```

Usage:

```
if(distance<10) //10 depend on location accuracy 
{
  //Notification 
}
```

Comment: Using Location Service Refer : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0